# When I try to filter my data and then apply a sort, I get back all results

Tags: c#

I need help thinking about how to solve this problem.

I'm used a DropDown to filter out a table which works. After that, if I click on one of the headings to sort, I get back all the results. How should I be thinking about this problem?  I've been creating new DataTable when I filter it.

My Page Load:

```
   DataTable courses;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            string campus = Request.QueryString["campus"];


            var s = Workforce.DataLayer.Connection(campus);
            courses = Workforce.DataLayer.GetCourseList(s); GridView1.DataSource = courses;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here's my DropDown.

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "All")
    {
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");
        return;
    }
    var query = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    DataTable tblFiltered = courses.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(row => row.Field<String>("category") == query).CopyToDataTable();


    courses = tblFiltered.Copy();
    GridView1.DataSource = tblFiltered;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Sort Handling when you click on a header:

```
 protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            string SortDirection = "ASC";
            if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
            {
                if (ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() == e.SortExpression)
                {
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = null;
                    SortDirection = "DESC";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
            }

            DataTable dt = courses;
            DataView custView = new DataView(dt);

            custView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDirection;
            GridView1.DataSource = custView;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Does Workforce.DataLayer.GetCourseList return an IQueryable?

Comment: it returns a datatable.

Comment: Does GridView1.DataSource get populated anywhere else? If so make sure that it is filtering by the dropdown too.

Comment: Yes it does, by my GridView1_Sorting handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this in the sort:

```
DataView custView = new DataView(dt);

if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue != "All")
{
   custView.RowFilter = "category='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

}
custView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + SortDirection;
```

Comment: Each time that the page is loaded the courses collection is being refreshed. So the only time that your grid was being filtered was when the dropdown was changed.